# How to use tkinter grid() on instances of another class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I am currently trying to code a pdf merger in Python and I am using tkinter to code the GUI of my application. Please note that it is my first real project in Python.

I have coded a class for my main application and I created another class named browseButton to manipulate more easily a special type of button that inherits from tkinter.Button.

However, the buttons created through this class don't appear in the main application after using grid() to place them.

Here is my code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import openFile

class mainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.browseLabel=tk.Label(self, text='Select the 2 PDF files to merge.', anchor='w', fg='black')
        self.browseLabel.grid(row=1, columnspan=10, pady=20)

        createQuitButton(self)
        createMergeButton(self)

        self.browseButton1=browseButton(self)
        self.browseButton2=browseButton(self)

        self.browseButton1.button.grid(row=5, column=2)
        self.browseButton2.button.grid(row=5, column=9)
        self.browseButton1.buttonLabel.grid(row=4, column=2)
        self.browseButton2.buttonLabel.grid(row=4, column=9)

    def merge(self):
        pass

class browseButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.createButton()

    def openFile(self):
        openFile.askOpenFile()
        self.changeButtonLabel()

    def createButton(self):
        browseButton.buttonLabel=tk.Label(self, text='Select file', anchor='w', fg='black')
        browseButton.button=tk.Button(self, text='Browse', command=self.openFile)

    def changeButtonLabel(self):
        self.buttonLabel['text']='File Found!
```

Please can someone tell me why this is not working?

Comment: It's highly unusual to place a label and a button _inside_ a button, and is probably never the correct thing to do. What are you trying to accomplish by putting a label and a button inside another button?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I want to create a button allowing the user to browse their filesystem and select a pdf file. The way I view it, it should be a subclass of the tkinter.Button class and have its own method, called when it's clicked. The label is used to indicate to the user what they have to do, 'select file' and displays 'file found!' once the file has been open. Before creating this class, I created all the widgets in my initialize method and it was working well but I thought that it wasn't a nice way of approaching it!